# Subtract specific hours and days from a TimeSpan

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the time in hours and minutes between two dates. But also subtract certain hours and dates in that period.

Example:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2022,10,8,14,35,1)
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2022,11,1,17,46,62)
```

With:

```
Timespan ts = endDate.Subtract(starDate);
```

I get the whole timespan between the dates.

But I want to subtract all the time between:

- 00:OO - 08:00 on all days
- 19:00 - 24:00 on all days
- 00:00 — 24:00 Saturdays and Sundays
- 00:00 - 24:00 on specific dates

I can get the correct results for this but not very efficient.

Pseudo code:

```
int seconds = 0
while(startDate <= endDate)
{
 if(startDate not in excludedTime)
    seconds++;

 startDate = startDate.AddSeconds(1);
}
```

There must be a more efficent way of doing this?

Comment: Based on the given data, what's the expected outcome?

Comment: Are you just applying the exclusions to the start date? Or also the end date? Or all the dates in between as well? As @Chetan said, please show the expected result.

Comment: I know this was closed, and someone had answered below, but [I had a fiddle open](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsoWZa) with something that may be easier for you to follow (or not). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to write one method that will adjust a date based on the weekend/holiday rules, another to get the timespan from a day based on the working hour rules, and then a third that utilizes these to add up the timespans for each day in a range.

For the first method, I've added a `bool forward` argument that we can set to `false` for adjusting the end date, since presumably the implementation of moving a date backwards is slightly different. Note that when moving a day to a new day, I use the `.Date` property of the result to reset the time information:

```
public static DateTime AdjustDate(DateTime input, bool forward = true)
{
    var skipDates = new List<DateTime>
    { 
        // add a comma-separated list of dates to skip here 
    };

    while (skipDates.Contains(input.Date)) 
        input = input.AddDays(forward ? 1 : -1).Date;

    if (input.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) 
        input = input.AddDays(forward ? 2 : -1).Date;
    if (input.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
        input = input.AddDays(forward ? 1 : -2).Date;
    
    return input;
}
```

Once we have that method working, we need one that will get us the timespan for just the specific working hours of that day. Once again we have a bool argument that specifies if we're counting hours FROM the start of the day or TO the end of the day. Then we can add logic to adjust the actual hour of the date and do our math based on the specified start and end hours for a day.

```
public static TimeSpan GetNetTimeSpan(DateTime input, bool fromStart = true)
{
    if (input.Hour > 19)
    {
        if (fromStart) 
            input = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, 19, 0, 0);
        else return TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
    if (input.Hour < 8)
    {
        if (fromStart) return TimeSpan.Zero;
        else input = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, 8, 0, 0);
    }

    if (fromStart)
    {
        return input - new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, 8, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, 19, 0, 0) - input;
    }
}
```

With these in place, we should now be able to loop through all the days and create a timespan that encapsulates the valid ticks of each day:

```
public static TimeSpan GetNetDifference(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    // First, adjust our start and end dates to avoid weekends and holidays
    start = AdjustDate(start);
    end = AdjustDate(end, false);

    // If our start is no longer less than our end, return zero
    if (start >= end) return TimeSpan.Zero;

    // Begin with the start date timespan
    var result = GetNetTimeSpan(start);

    // Next loop through each day between start and end and add them to the result
    var current = AdjustDate(start.AddDays(1).Date);

    while(current.Date < end.Date)
    {
        result += GetNetTimeSpan(current);
        current = AdjustDate(current.AddDays(1).Date);
    }

    // Add our last day and return the result
    return result + GetNetTimeSpan(end);
}
```

I haven't tested it, partly because it's not completely clear if this follows your rules, but it should give you a good starting point.

Also, it would be more flexible if we parameterized the start and end times rather than having them hard-coded at 8 and 19.